# Is this disclosure button like view a standard view?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

There is a view used frequently in Mac applications, for example, Mail, iTunes: [image]. But I didn't find it in the library. Is there any third-party implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's included or not, but you can use any kind of icon inside a button.

Comment: Yes, I can draw it. But how to make it 100% accurate. There is no specifications.